# Firebase Analytics (Android): Events show up in StreamView and DebugView but not in Dashboard and BigQuery

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

We have an app on both iOS and Android on which we use Firebase Analytics. In our dev environment everything works OK, but when we moved it to production, the iOS version continued to work OK, but the Android analytics don't show up in the dashboard. When we checked StreamView we see that events are being streamed, and when we checked DebugView, we can see the events streaming correctly. However, nothing shows up in the dashboard or in BigQuery.

Would appreciate any guidance on where we should look to fix this, and if anyone else has experienced similar issues? I would think that if it shows the events streaming in StreamView that it would show up in the dashboard.

Thanks!

EDIT: Firebase Support has come back to me and attributed it to the reuse of the package name, which is a known problem and informed me that a fix for production was forthcoming. As of 25th of May, analytics events have been captured and it looks like the problem is resolved. Thanks!

[image: StreamView showing events being streamed]

Comment: Hi Francisco. :) Just to clarify, are you seeing *no data* at all on the dashboard or were you expecting that the data seen in StreamView/DebugView are to be the same as should be in the Dashboard?

Comment: Hi AL! Yeah, the dashboard is showing the "Your analytics data will appear here soon" screen. Initially we thought it was just the 24 hour lag, but we released the app 2 days ago and seeing events in StreamView and DebugView, but no summary in the dashboard. On iOS it seems fine, and on a previous development instance of Firebase (using the exact same code, but with the corresponding Firebase config file). Thanks!

Comment: Odd. I would suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) directly to have a better look at this on their side.

Comment: Thanks! We were coming to that but thought we'd follow the suggested support flow of googling, then asking the community.

Comment: Did you delete your project and reuse the same package ID? I think there is a known bug and you should contact Firebase support with your Google App ID.

Comment: No worries Francisco. :) Actually, I've seen some previous posts with the same scenario before and the end result is to reach out to Firebase Support through email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Support has come back to me and attributed it to the reuse of the package name, which is a known problem and informed me that a fix for production was forthcoming. As of 25th of May, analytics events have been captured and it looks like the problem is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: And i am facing the same issue now.

Comment: I am facing this issue in Oct 17.

Comment: After updpating firebase sdk to 11.4.2, the issue resolves and it got the events logged on dashboard.